# Access control on Redis

Tags: redis

I'd like to limit the way Redis is used for the applications that access it, as well as for users so that not every application/user has access to all data.

Is there a way of doing access control on Redis so that applications are only allowed to access certain keys and not others?

Comment: @Nebras FYI: `databases` property from `redis.conf` allow to set more than 16 databases.

Comment: I think there is no direct way to do that. As a suggestion you can use a database for each application so the connector of this application will access only keys and values stored in the configured database.  @maxd, you are right.. the default database number is 16. It could be changed in `redis.conf`. thanks @madx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the moment. Currently Redis provides a single authorization password per Redis server, which grants full admin and data access to all (shared/numbered) databases in it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is No, This should be handled in the application end.

> While Redis does not try to implement Access Control, it provides a tiny layer of authentication that is optionally turned on editing the redis.conf file.
>   -redis.io

As mentioned above redis provide only a tiny layer of authentication, everything else should be handled by the application.